# kotlin android nav graph go back causes recreate a old fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I Have huge probleme in my project when I go back from fragment B to fragment A just like this :

```
findNavController().navigateUp()
```

or

```
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

causes that a old fragment is recreated And I do not why

this is my action:

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />






 val action = ScanningFragmentDirections.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB(
            scanningViewModel.containerLevel,
            container
        )
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(action)



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
     binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.scanning_fragment, container, false)
    binding!!.viewmodel = scanningViewModel
    binding!!.lifecycleOwner = this
    return binding!!.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    init()
}
```

Comment: please post your "navigate to" action. Are you using app:popUpTo?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I put my action

Comment: that seems fine, put your code where you use action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi i put code

Comment: probably, as @ianhanniballake said, your fragment is kept in the backstack but your view is destroyed. In the onViewCreated method you should have the logic to recreate you UI. Can you please post your fragmentA code?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I put my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223719/discussion-between-nicola-gallazzi-and-kiki-kala2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you navigate from one fragment to another your fragment **view** is destroyed(`onDestroyView` is called). When you navigate back to a fragment you previously were in the view is recreated (`onCreateView` is called).

There may be scenarios wherein you do not want your fragment to be recreated (Some time ago I had a fragment with a `MapView` and I didn't want to have to add all the different markers and polygons again). You can try something like this:

Create a field in your fragment class to save your view:

```kotlin
private lateinit var contentView: View
```

In the `onCreateView` function only inflate the view if your variable has not been intialised.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    if (!::contentView.isInitialized) {
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    } 

    return contentView
}
```

Comment: this answer works fine for views what about having data on view model every time you press back it will call you API

Comment: @anwarsamir It's impossible to say what's going on without having a look at your implementation. You may want to post a question regarding your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you calling `findNavController().navigate(...)` under the hood system calling :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(mContainerId, frag);
```

That mean that your fragment will be fully destroyed and recreate again when you return to him via backstack.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Documentations says: "Android maintains a back stack that contains the destinations you've visited. The first destination of your app is placed on the stack when the user opens the app. Each call to the navigate() method puts another destination on top of the stack. Tapping Up or Back calls the NavController.navigateUp() and NavController.popBackStack() methods, respectively, to remove (or pop) the top destination off of the stack."

Comment: Yeah, your old fragment isn't "fully destroyed" at all. The fragment's *view* is, on the other hand, destroyed and recreated.

Comment: So what I have to do ? I do not want recreatemy old fragment

Comment: you should save and restore the ui state of your fragment